# Adding graphics to iPhone application

Tags: iphone, photoshop

I am curious of how other prepare graphic content for the "regular" iPhone screen and the new iPhone Retina screen, with double the density and pixels. Do you make the graphic match the pixels on the new Retina screen and then saving the "big" picture but scale it down 50%?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question. Is there an "Art Overflow" or some such you could ask it on?

Comment: @Jonathan: this is definitely a programming question, but that's still a pretty funny comment.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: It just seemed to be more a question for graphic designers rather than computer programmers. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we make the graphic match the pixels on the new Retina screen and then saving the "big" picture but scale it down 50%. :)

Answer (score 1):

We are using separate images for normal and retina diiplays. So for example we have image named img1.png . The for retina display we'll create img1@2x.png  (2x bigger) and when calling the 
[UIImage imageNamed: @"img1.png"] sdk would determine automatically which one to take.